# Mylyn WikiText Textile parsing error?

Tags: java, mylyn, textile, wikitext

I'm working on migrating a textile plugin for a java blogging platform from one library (textile4j) to Mylyn's WikiText. So far very promising, but I have some unit tests that are failing:

```
public void testLinksSyntax44() {
    String in = "\"link text(with title)\":http://example.com/";
    String out = "<p><a href=\"http://example.com/\" title=\"with title\">link text</a></p>";
    textile.parse(in);
    String content = writer.toString();
    assertEquals(out, content);
}

public void testLinksSyntax46() {
    String in = "\"(link)link text(with title)\":http://example.com/";
    String out = "<p><a href=\"http://example.com/\" class=\"link\" title=\"with title\">link text</a></p>";
    textile.parse(in);
    String content = writer.toString();
    assertEquals(out, content);
}
```

Basically, the output is showing a problem with WikiText parsing the `title` syntax. The output for each test is as follows:

In #44, the output is: `<p><a href="http://example.com/">link text(with title)</a></p>`

In #46, the output is: `<p><a href="http://example.com/" class="link">link text(with title)</a></p>`

The Textpattern Textile web widget correctly parses the link with class and title (`"(link)link text(with title)":http://www.example.com/`) and the link with title (`"link text(with title)":http://www.example.com/`) short forms.

Am I doing something wrong, or did I find a bug? I'm still groking the library, but it might be that one familiar with the library knows the problem, can find the error, or can help correct me.

Much thanks!
Tim

Comment: I'm using the standalone builds of Mylyn WikiText BTW from Maven Central, v1.3. The code appears to be pushed from github and I have PMs to both devs (one the original, one a clone) at github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the bug has been reported...

[Eclipse Mylyn WikiText Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327249)