# Are there any Java examples using Mylyn WikiText?

Tags: java, html, mylyn-wikitext

I want to use Java to code a conversion from Mylyn Wiki-supported formats to HTML.  I have found no helpful online examples demonstrating how to use Java to code for Mylyn WikiText.  I have only found [this page on Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui/help/Markup-Conversion.html), but it uses Ant.  I request some example code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can always [code Ant Scripts and launch them from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733684/run-ant-from-java), below is a complete utility class that I just wrote, which will let you convert wiki text via the various core languages registered to the WikiText standalone deployment.

Of note, the simplest thing to do is [download the Standalone Deployment](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/), expand it and read through the API to see what other configurations you need to apply.

Converting WikiText to HTML

```java
package com.stackoverflow.mylyn;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.parser.MarkupParser;
import org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.parser.builder.HtmlDocumentBuilder;
import org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.parser.markup.MarkupLanguage;
import org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.util.ServiceLocator;

/**
 * Utility to parse Wiki Text of varying languages and convert to HTML.
 */
public final class ParseWikiToHTMLUtility {

    public static final String NAME_TEXTILE = "Textile";
    public static final String NAME_TRACWIKI = "TracWiki";
    public static final String NAME_MEDIAWIKI = "MediaWiki";
    public static final String NAME_CONFLUENCE = "Confluence";
    public static final String NAME_TWIKI = "TWiki";

    private ParseWikiToHTMLUtility() {
            /* Do not instantiate utility classes */
    }

    public static String parseTextile(String wikiText) {

            return parseByLanguage(NAME_TEXTILE, wikiText);
    }

    public static String parseTracWiki(String wikiText) {

            return parseByLanguage(NAME_TRACWIKI, wikiText);
    }

    public static String parseMediaWiki(String wikiText) {

            return parseByLanguage(NAME_MEDIAWIKI, wikiText);
    }

    public static String parseConfluence(String wikiText) {

            return parseByLanguage(NAME_CONFLUENCE, wikiText);
    }

    public static String parseTWiki(String wikiText) {

            return parseByLanguage(NAME_TWIKI, wikiText);
    }

    public static String parseByLanguage(String name, String wikiText) {

            return parseByLanguage(ServiceLocator.getInstance().getMarkupLanguage(name), wikiText);
    }

    public static String parseByLanguage(MarkupLanguage language, String wikiText) {

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            HtmlDocumentBuilder builder = new HtmlDocumentBuilder(writer);
            MarkupParser parser = new MarkupParser(language, builder);
            parser.parse(wikiText);
            return writer.toString();                
    }

    /**
     * MarkupLanguage API prefers we retrieve the MarkupLanguge by name from 
     * the ServiceLocator; since there are no name constants, we obtain the names 
     * from this method or alternately use the hard-coded names from this utility class, 
     * which were pulled directly from a prior call to this very method. 
     */
    public static Set<String> getLanguageNames() {

            Set<String> languages = new TreeSet<String>();
            for (MarkupLanguage s : ServiceLocator.getInstance().getAllMarkupLanguages()) {
                    languages.add(s.getName());
            }

            return languages;
    }        
}
```

To transform from HTML, use the `HtmlParser.parse()` method.  Submit your HTML as an `InputSource` and provide a `DocumentBuilder` target.  `DocumentBuilder` implementations include `XslfoDocumentBuilder` (for XSL-Fo and eventual transformation to PDF or PostScript), `DocBookDocumentBuilder` (for Docbook format), and classes which extend `AbstractMarkupDocumentBuilder` (there's one for almost every markup: `TextileDocumentBuilder`, `ConfluenceDocumentBuilder`, etc.).

Other WikiText links:

- [How to use Mylyn WikiText in Java](http://pastorcmentarny.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-use-mylyn-wikitext-in-java.html) (has some sample code)
- [SO question about parsing with WikiText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702131/mylyn-wikitext-textile-parsing-error) (has some sample code)
- [WikiText Developer Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui/help/devguide/WikiText%20Developer%20Guide.html) for Eclipse integration
- [Getting started with WikiText](http://www.peterfriese.de/getting-started-with-wikitext/) (1 of 2)
- [Advanced WikiText](http://www.peterfriese.de/advanced-wikitext/) (2 of 2)
- [Comparison of converters where WikiText wins](http://blog.makk.es/2011/02/java-libs-to-process-wiki-markup.html)

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.parser.builder.HtmlDocumentBuilder

Comment: Here a plain maven example (for the markdown language): https://gist.github.com/jmini/58f66c1bd5d0203c5f67